# WSO2 : Can't wipe data

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've set up WSO2 IOT server 3.1.0 but i can't wipe data :

> Erreur in notification :  WIPE_DATA operation failed to execute on
>   device xxx (ID: xxxxxx)

Can you help me?
thanks.

---

Here's logs.

```
11-09 15:48:34.912 24757 24757 D org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AlarmReceiver: Recurring alarm; requesting alarm service.
11-09 15:48:34.923 24757 27610 D OperationManager: New OperationManager created.

11-09 15:48:34.924 24757 27610 I MessageProcessor: Get pending operations from:http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8280/api/device-mgt/android/v1.0/devices/2bd583e008ccbf2f/pending-operations
11-09 15:48:34.925 24757 27610 D MessageProcessor: Reply Payload: []
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D APIController: APIController created.
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D APIController: invokeAPI called
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D IdentityProxy: requestToken called.
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D IdentityProxy: token is expired false
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D IdentityProxy: token expiry Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:34.926 24757 27610 D IdentityProxy: Using Access Token: efc13b79-ffba-334f-84a1-62b4eaa4fff7
11-09 15:48:34.936 24757 25055 D APIController: Retrieved token expires on:Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:34.938 24757 25055 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:34.938 24757 25055 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:35.002 24757 25055 D APIController: Result :[{"enabled":true,"code":"APPLICATION_LIST","type":"COMMAND","id":107,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:48:25.862","isEnabled":false},{"code":"WIPE_DATA","type":"PROFILE","id":106,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:47:46.023","isEnabled":true,"payLoad":"{\"pin\":\"3381\"}"}]
11-09 15:48:35.005 24757 25055 D MessageProcessor: Pending Operations List: [{"enabled":true,"code":"APPLICATION_LIST","type":"COMMAND","id":107,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:48:25.862","isEnabled":false},{"code":"WIPE_DATA","type":"PROFILE","id":106,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:47:46.023","isEnabled":true,"payLoad":"{\"pin\":\"3381\"}"}]
11-09 15:48:35.017 24757 25055 D MessageProcessor: Restarting to send quick update of received pending operations.
11-09 15:48:35.020 24757 25055 I LocalNotification: Polling stopped!
11-09 15:48:35.025 24757 25055 I LocalNotification: Polling started! Interval: 30000
11-09 15:48:35.727 24757 24757 D LocationService: Status changed to: 2 Provider: gps
11-09 15:48:36.113 24757 25055 D OperationManager: Application list sent
11-09 15:48:36.114 24757 25055 D OperationManagerBYOD: Started to wipe data
11-09 15:48:36.116 24757 24757 D APIController: [{"enabled":true,"code":"APPLICATION_LIST","type":"COMMAND","id":107,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:48:25.862","isEnabled":false},{"code":"WIPE_DATA","type":"PROFILE","id":106,"status":"PENDING","createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:47:46.023","isEnabled":true,"payLoad":"{\"pin\":\"3381\"}"}]
11-09 15:48:36.662 24757 24757 D org.wso2.iot.agent.services.AlarmReceiver: Recurring alarm; requesting alarm service.
11-09 15:48:36.669 24757 27621 D OperationManager: New OperationManager created.

11-09 15:48:36.670 24757 27621 I MessageProcessor: Get pending operations from:http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8280/api/device-mgt/android/v1.0/devices/2bd583e008ccbf2f/pending-operations
11-09 15:48:36.680 24757 27621 D MessageProcessor: Reply Payload: [{"code":"APPLICATION_LIST","complianceType":null,"createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:48:25.862","enabled":true,"id":107,"operationResponse":"[{\"name\":\"ES%20Explorateur%20de%20Fichiers\",\"package\":\"com.estrongs.android.pop\",\"version\":\"4.1.6.9.6\",\"isSystemApp\":false,\"isActive\":false},{\"name\":\"ipconfig\",\"package\":\"com.mankind.ipconfig\",\"version\":\"1.1\",\"isSystemApp\":false,\"isActive\":false},{\"name\":\"WSO2%20Device%20Management%20Agent\",\"package\":\"org.wso2.iot.agent\",\"version\":\"3.1.21\",\"isSystemApp\":false,\"isActive\":true,\"USS\":30948},{\"name\":\"Google%20Play%20services%20for%20Instant%20Apps\",\"package\":\"com.google.android.instantapps.supervisor\",\"version\":\"2.3-release-174342078\",\"isSystemApp\":false,\"isActive\":false},{\"name\":\"QR%20Scanner\",\"package\":\"com.application_4u.qrcode.barcode\",\"version\":\"1.9.6\",\"isSystemApp\":false,\"isActive\":false}]","payLoad":null,"receivedTimeStamp":null,"status":"COMPLETED","type":"COMMAND"},{"code":"WIPE_DATA","complianceType":null,"createdTimeStamp":"2017-11-09 15:47:46.023","enabled":false,"id":106,"operationResponse":null,"payLoad":{"status":"true"},"receivedTimeStamp":null,"status":"COMPLETED","type":"PROFILE"}]
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D APIController: APIController created.
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D APIController: invokeAPI called
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D IdentityProxy: requestToken called.
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D IdentityProxy: token is expired false
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D IdentityProxy: token expiry Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:36.681 24757 27621 D IdentityProxy: Using Access Token: efc13b79-ffba-334f-84a1-62b4eaa4fff7
11-09 15:48:36.686 24757 25057 D APIController: Retrieved token expires on:Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:36.688 24757 25057 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.688 24757 24757 D LocationService: Location changed> lat:47.2659288 lon:-1.4888419 provider:network
11-09 15:48:36.688 24757 25057 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D APIController: APIController created.
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D APIController: invokeAPI called
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D IdentityProxy: requestToken called.
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D IdentityProxy: token is expired false
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D IdentityProxy: token expiry Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:36.694 24757 24757 D IdentityProxy: Using Access Token: efc13b79-ffba-334f-84a1-62b4eaa4fff7
11-09 15:48:36.695 24757 24757 D LocationService: Location Event is published.
11-09 15:48:36.697 24757 25056 D APIController: Retrieved token expires on:Thu Nov 09 15:50:42 GMT+01:00 2017
11-09 15:48:36.698 24757 25056 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.699 24757 25056 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.700 24757 24757 D LocationService: Location changed> lat:47.2659288 lon:-1.4888419 provider:network
11-09 15:48:36.702 24757 24757 D LocationService: Ignore publishing. Duplicate location timestamp.
11-09 15:48:36.704 24757 24757 D LocationUpdateReceiver: Location> Lat:47.2659288 Lon:-1.4888419 Provider:network
11-09 15:48:36.707 24757 25058 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.707 24757 25058 I System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
11-09 15:48:36.709 24757 24757 D LocationUpdateReceiver: Location> Lat:47.2659288 Lon:-1.4888419 Provider:network
11-09 15:48:36.733 24757 24757 D LocationService: Status changed to: 2 Provider: gps
11-09 15:48:36.751 24757 25056 D APIController: Result :{"responseCode":"Event is published successfully."}
11-09 15:48:36.751 24757 25056 D org.wso2.iot.agent.events.publisher.HttpDataPublisher: Result for request: 312 is 201
11-09 15:48:36.753 24757 24757 D APIController: {"responseCode":"Event is published successfully."}
```

In logs, everythings seems to be ok.
Thanks for help.

Comment: is this iOS or Android?

Comment: Could you also tell if this is a client side log or a server log? If this is a client side log, can you describe the environment? eg- device type, OS version
Have you tested on a different device as well and see consistent results?

Comment: It is android. It's a server log. I don't have anymore details, because the log is in notifications. centos 7, Android version 7.0 and 5.0. On android 5.0, it says that wipe is a success but the phone does not reboot and does not make wipe.. thanks for help. If you need more logs, can you tell me where i can found them?

Comment: I just add a comment to say that i get an error on wipe when i set up a work profile. when no set up profile is set, consle says that wipe is completed but nothing happen on terminal. tested on android 5.0 and 7.0.

Comment: Noone has an answer?

Comment: Alex, would you be able to enable debug in agents side by setting the DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED constant to true and resend the WIPE operation and share the Android logs? That's the best way to further analyze this. You can share the output of the Logcat window in Android Studio.

Comment: Alex also note that what madhawa suggested involve recompiling the agent and you can do that by following the documentation[1]

[1]. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS310/Customizing+the+Android+APK+File

Comment: I've created apk in debug mode. DEBUG_MODE_ENABLED is true in this "version". in cmd : >adb -d logcat org.wso2.iot.agent:I *:S but no logs displayed.

Comment: I found some logs. But it's very long. I put it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found issue with the wipe operation on Android and we have fixed this with the new release of our android agent which is capable with IoT Server 3.1.0.

Please find the apk file and the new source code [here](https://github.com/wso2/cdmf-agent-android/releases/tag/v3.1.23).

Thanks,